# Why in this scala snippet the compiler loses the type [P] of the payload? How can I make this snippet compile?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

I'd like to construct a specific envelope for specific payload types

```
object test {
    // marker traits for different payload types
    sealed trait Payload
    sealed trait PayloadA extends Payload
    sealed trait PayloadB extends Payload

    // general envelope type
    sealed trait Envelope[+T <: Payload] {
     def p: T
    }
    // specific envelopes
    case class EnvelopeA[+T <: PayloadA](p: T) extends Envelope[T]
    case class EnvelopeB[+T <: PayloadB](p: T) extends Envelope[T]

    // constructor
    object Envelope {
        def apply[P <: Payload](p: P): Envelope[P] = p match {
            case a: PayloadA => EnvelopeA(a)
            case b: PayloadB => EnvelopeB(b)
        }
    }

}
```

Compiling above snippet produces following errors:

```
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type test.PayloadA)
 required: P
                   case a: PayloadA => EnvelopeA(a)
                                                 ^
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type test.PayloadB)
 required: P
                   case b: PayloadB => EnvelopeB(b)
                                                 ^
```

Which is a bit surprising because I'd expect the compiler to infer the type of p to be `PayloadA with P` or `PayloadB with P`, `PayloadX` because of the pattern match and `with P` because of the definition of the `apply` method.

But the `with P` part is lost.

So the question is why is this happening and how can I fix the code without resorting to the type classes?

(I have to keep this general structure in place because of the requirements towards some legacy code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that `a` inside the `case` is known by the compiler to be a subtype of type `PayloadA` but by this time it lost the knowledge that this is the same object as `p` so it is also a subtype of `P`. I see a few ways to make this code work:

One way is to say to the compiler "I know better" and add explicit casts such as:

```
object Envelope {
  def apply[P <: Payload](p: P): Envelope[P] = p match {
    case a: PayloadA => EnvelopeA(a).asInstanceOf[Envelope[P]]
    case b: PayloadB => EnvelopeB(b).asInstanceOf[Envelope[P]]
  }
}
```

A similar way to say "I know better" is to make a `case` that will include the generic `P` such as

```
  def apply[P <: Payload](p: P): Envelope[P] = p match {
    case a: P with PayloadA => EnvelopeA(a)
    case b: P with PayloadB => EnvelopeB(b)
  }
```

Note that this will generate a warning like

> abstract type pattern P is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>   
>         case a: P with PayloadA => EnvelopeA(a)

Finally there is a way that uses a more advanced Scala feature: implicits. The code goes like this:

```
trait EnvelopeBuilder[P <: Payload] {
  def buildEnvelope(p: P): Envelope[P]
}

object EnvelopeBuilder {
  implicit def aEnvelopeBuilder[P <: PayloadA] = new EnvelopeBuilder[P] {
    override def buildEnvelope(p: P) = EnvelopeA(p)
  }

  implicit def bEnvelopeBuilder[P <: PayloadB] = new EnvelopeBuilder[P] {
    override def buildEnvelope(p: P) = EnvelopeB(p)
  }
}

// constructor
object Envelope {
  def apply[P <: Payload](p: P)(implicit eb: EnvelopeBuilder[P]): Envelope[P] = eb.buildEnvelope(p)
}
```

You may find some more details on the idea for the second solution in the ["Type classes in Scala" article](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html).

One advantage of this last approach is type-safety. If you add a new direct child `PayloadC` but don't add `EnvelopeC` and corresponding `implicit def`, the code will not compile rather than failing at runtime as with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign value of `p match {` to a variable you will see that type of that variable is `Product with Serializable with Envelope[Payload] { .. }`. However signature of your apply method requires value of a more strict type to be returned: `Envelope[P]`. `Envelope[P]` is more strict type as P is a subclass of Payload. As you can't return value of more general type instead of more specific type (i.e. you can't return any Fruit when Orange is expected) you get the error.
In order to fix it you can change signature of your apply method to expect `Envelope[Payload]`.

Comment: Yeah, the question is basically why is p is of type `Payload` if it is known to be more specific `P` at the time of the function application